# What do you call a person who collects recipes, ingredients or other cooking related materials?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who collects recipes, ingredients or other cooking related materials? Is there a name for classifications like this (like *taxonomy* etc.)?

Comment: Maybe a cup-boarder, sounding like hoarder? Or just straight up cup-hoarder?

Answer (score 13):

While several terms loosely fit the criteria (such as a *culinarian*), a *culinophile* or *reagenteur* speaks more to my tastes (if you don't mind [portmanteaux](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Portmanteau)).

As for what one might call the group, *taxonomy* or *classification* are appropriate when ascribing the term to a family derived from a particular set of criteria. Plenty of additional terms [are available in online Thesauri,](http://thesaurus.com/browse/taxonomy) if you're curious.

Comment: +1 purely for introducing me to 'partmanteux'. I shall impress people with it over the dining table at Christmas.

Comment: @CJM Reciprocal +1, for making my morning with this comment.

Comment: And you'd get a +1 for me if had spelled portmanteau right

Comment: portmanteaux is the plural of portmanteau

Comment: @Bruno I'm assuming the statement relates to the misspelling "partmanteux" in CJM's comment. As for my own usage, it's a deliberate pluralization as noted.

Answer (score 2):

"Foodie" (although that suggests someone interested in preparing and eating the food too).

Answer (score 1):

I would say **food enthusiast**, or maybe **food lover** (though the second is too close to “someone who loves food in great quantity” for me to be completely confortable with it).

Answer (score 0):

How about the term "culinary collector"? It seems to be both precise and general enough, while remaining straightforward and unpretentious. Additional subheadings could be inserted, such as those for literature (cookbooks, articles, essays and recipes); equipment (antique, specialty or regional); videos (cooking shows, travelogues, even historic/cultural documentaries).