# Classification of culinary related item called?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

[Related to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6463/what-do-you-call-this-person), what is the classification of culinary items like (ingredients, spices, cooking materials called?)

Answer (score 1):

The group "ingredients" is diverse and so also is the group "cooking materials", as this could include utensils, for instance. I would use the term "condiments" to refer to all spices, seasonings, sauces and other substances that add flavor to food.

Answer (score 0):

I think the umbrella term that would cover all classifications of culinary items is *food preparation*.

For example [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_food_preparation) outlines the following sub-classifications under food preparation:

> - Food preparation techniques
>
>   > - Cooking techniques
>   > - Chemical techniques
> - Cuisines
> - General ingredients

Also it lists some of the food preparation concepts that would fall under classifications.